# DevExpress Где найти хелп на русском языке с примерами?

Tags: devexpress

Где найти хелп для визуализатора DevExpress на русском языке с примерами?

Comment: что именно ты хочешь найти?

Comment: Все тоже самое только на русском https://www.devexpress.com/

Comment: Либо у тебя не вся ссылка скопировалась, либо ты дал ссылку на главную страницу

Comment: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114558